# Каким образом можно заставить добавлять текст в StringBuilder по регулярным выражениям?

Tags: java, алгоритм, регулярные-выражения, строки, итераторы

Допустим, есть определенный текст на входе, нужно чтобы метод с регулярными выражениями выводил все тот же текст, в том же порядке, но, к примеру, в словах, имеющих в себе большие буквы, вместо первой буквы ставил восьмерку. То есть из текста

```
To be, or not to be, that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
```

он бы вывел

```
8o be, or not to be, that is the question:
8hether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
```

Каким образом такое можно сделать? Использовать итератор?

Comment: то есть ваша задача - это заменить все большие буквы на восьмерки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, к примеру, написать такой метод:

```
public static String replace(String str, char replaceTo) {
    return str.chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> Character.isUpperCase((char) ch) ? replaceTo : (char) ch)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    StringBuilder::new,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::toString));
}
```